# Meteor app with DataTables: how to capture the value of selected table row

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatables

In my meteor app I have the following table, which is wrapped in data table):

```
<template name="IntroductionWizard_Step_2">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Introduction Wizard Step 2: </h3>
                        <h3>Select an Application to describe</h3>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="apptable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>App ID</th>
                                <th>App Name</th>
                                <th>In Scope</th>
                                <th>App Owner</th>
                                <th>BU</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            {{#each appList}}
                                {{>appRow}}
                            {{/each}}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br />

                </div>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="appRow">
     <tr>
     <td>{{AppId}} </td>
        <td>{{AppName}} </td>
        <td>{{InScope}} </td>
        <td>{{AppOwner}}</td>
        <td>{{Bu}}</td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

Here is the handler for this datatable:

```
Template.IntroductionWizard_Step_2.rendered = function(){
  console.log('wizard.js: IntroductionWizard_Step_2 is rendered');

  /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#apptable').dataTable( );

$("#apptable tbody tr").on('click',function(event) {
    $("#apptable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');    
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
  });  
}
```

My question is: how do I capture the value of the selected/clicked table row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you might want to use [Meteor's own template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) rather than the jQuery event handler. But either way, within your `click` event handler the `event.target` object should refer to the `tr` that was clicked.

So all you need to do is update your `appRow` template such that each `tr` tag has an `id` or `data-someIdentifierOfYourChoosing` attribute that holds the `_id` or other identifier that you're trying to track for that row. Then within the handler, `$(event.target).prop('id')` or `$(event.target).data('someIdentifierOfYourChoosing')` should retrieve it.

**EDIT** Here's an example (untested):

```
<template name="appRow">
  <tr data-mongoId="{{_id}}">
    <td>{{AppId}}</td>
    <td>{{AppName}}</td>
    <td>{{InScope}}</td>
    <td>{{AppOwner}}</td>
    <td>{{Bu}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

and:

```
Template.appRow.events({
  "click tr": function (event) {
    var theRowThatWasClicked = event.target;
    var mongoIdOfThatRow = $(event.target).data("mongoId");
    // Then do whatever you want with those values; update the database, etc.

    // Copying/updating your code from your comment for completeness:
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(event.target);
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
    var value = fnGetSelected( oTable ).AppName;
    console.log(aData);
    $("#apptable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');
    $(event.target).addClass('row_selected');
  });
```

See also the [Live HTML templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtmltemplates) section of the Meteor docs.

Comment: For now, I ended up with this: Template.IntroductionWizard_Step_2.rendered = function(){
  console.log('wizard.js: IntroductionWizard_Step_2 is rendered');

  /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#apptable').dataTable( );

$("#apptable tbody tr").on('click',function(event) {
  var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(event.target);
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
  var value = fnGetSelected( oTable ).AppName;
  console.log(aData);
    $("#apptable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');    
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
  });  
}    Can I do this the meteor way (any example)